# Регулярка, замена текста смайлами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно пропустить текст через функцию/регулярку, что бы была произведена замена смайлов. Текстовый шаблон в виде `:smile_(номер):`

Вход: `Текст :smile_5: текст текст :smile_1: текст`

Выход: `Текст <img src="/5.png"> текст текст <img src="/1.png"> текст`

Как сделать, намекните, я в регулярках 0.

Comment: к моему решению. если вы добавляете $text в базу данных, то обязательно использовать htmlspecialchars($text) и mysqli_real_escape_string($text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
<?php
$text = 'Текст :smile_5: текст текст :smile_1: текст';
$text = preg_replace('/:smile_(.*?):/', '<img src="/$1.png">', $text);

echo $text;
?>
```

P.S. Если вы добавляете `$text` в базу данных, то обязательно использовать `htmlspecialchars($text)` и `mysqli_real_escape_string($text)`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41483/discussion-on-answer-by-ikerya----).

Answer (score 1):

не нужна тут регулярка используй `string_replace`

```
$arrayText = array(
    ':smile1:',
    ':smile2:'
);

$arrayPic = array(
    '<img src="/test/smile1.gif"/>',
    '<img src="/test/smile2.gif"/>'
);

$message = str_replace($arrayText,$arrayPic,$message);
```

Comment: Перечислять все смайлы? Не то, массивы не подойдут.

Comment: @Rammsteinik Забить мозг серверу регуляркой и оставить сотню уязвимостей типо `:smile_<script>alert('xss')</script>` или `:smile_<?php echo 'test'; ?>` самое то